# Retrieve Facebook reach for a past period with their API?

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

In the same way we can retrieve Facebook's [predictive reach for the future](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reachandfrequency), I have found their Targeting API which only retrieves the reach for a page/account but not all of facebook based on Platform/Age groups. Is there a way to get their past data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Facebook and looking at their API, this functionality is not available.